# vim find all _ except \sm_<some varaible name>

Tags: regex, vim, full-text-search

What regex can I use in vim to find all underscores except those used in the following:

`m_<some variable name>`

Comment: Since your question isnt specifying the variabke names, I guess that means you just  want all underscores except for ones preceded by an `m`

Comment: I am not sure if vim supports lookarounds. But if it does, then [this](https://regex101.com/r/pMlOcx/2) may work: `((?<!\bm)_)|((?<=\bm)_(?!<[a-zA-Z0-9]+>))`

Comment: Try `m\@<=_\(\w\)\@!\|m\@<!_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `<some variable name>` can only consist of alphanumeric characters (but not `_`), we can do a *negative lookbehind assertion* ([`:help /\@<!`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%21)) for `\<m` (i.e. a keyword must not start with `m` before the `_`)

```
/\%(\<m\)\@<!_/
```

Things get more complicated if `<some variable name>` can also contain underscores itself. We then have to exclude at the same position ([`:help /\@!`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%21)) matches before the underscore ([`:help /\@<=`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D)) of `\<m` and `\<m_\w*` and `\<m_\w*_\w*` and so on, ending with `\w*\>`:

```
/\%(\%(\<m\%(_\w*\)*\)\@<=_\w*\>\)\@!_/
```

That will also exclude `m_` itself. To fix that we need to differentiate (via two branches) between excluding underscore matches later in `\<m_\w*` and matches directly after `\<m` that then must have `\w\+` to have it excluded:

```
/\%(\%(\<m\%(_\w*\)\+\)\@<=_\w*\>\|\%(\<m\)\@<=_\w\+\>\)\@!_/
```